# JPA @Query Comparing > (bigger) with enums ignored

Tags: java, jpa, enums

I have the following query

```
@Query("select event from Event event where severity>0)    
public List<Event> getEvents();
```

where the "severity" property is an enum.
The enum class is below

```
package com.some.company.enums;

public enum EventSeverity {
    UNKNOWN(0),
    VALUE_1(1),
    VALUE_2(2),
    ...

    private final int severity;
    private EventSeverity(int severity) {
        this.severity = severity;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get events with *severity* greater than 0 (meaning **not** **UNKNOWN**)
but for some reason the query returns also results with **UNKNOWN** values

This is how the property is annotated in the Event Class

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "SEVERITY", nullable = false)
public EventSeverity getSeverity() {
    return this.severity;
}
```

Comment: How your annotate your enum field and how look like in DB?

Comment: From http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/comparison - "Enum values can be compared by using the equality operators (=, <>, ==, !=)".  Even if you could use the relative comparison operators (<, >) I would expect the behavior to be relative to the ordinal, not the internal severity value you have listed.

Comment: Try to change your query into `@Query("select event from Event event where event.severity > 0)`